# Java 8 lambda filtering based on condition as well as order

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I was trying to filter a list based on multiple conditions, sorting.

```
class Student{
        private int Age;
        private String className;
        private String Name;

        public Student(int age, String className, String name) {
            Age = age;
            this.className = className;
            Name = name;
        }

        public int getAge() {
            return Age;
        }

        public void setAge(int age) {
            Age = age;
        }

        public String getClassName() {
            return className;
        }

        public void setClassName(String className) {
            this.className = className;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return Name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            Name = name;
        }
    }
```

Now if I have a list of that, say

```
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
        students.add(new Student(24, "A", "Smith"));
        students.add(new Student(24, "A", "John"));
        students.add(new Student(30, "A", "John"));
        students.add(new Student(20, "B", "John"));
        students.add(new Student(24, "B", "Prince"));
```

How would I be able to get a list of the oldest students with a distinct name?
In C# this would be quite simple by using System.Linq GroupBy then comparing and then flattening with select, I'm not too sure how I could achieve the same in Java.

Comment: `students.stream().collect(groupingBy(...))`.

Comment: Do you only want a list of the oldest and only the oldest ones?

Comment: Please tell what is the desired result. I.e. How the map/list/whatever looks like.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the [`toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) collector:

```
Collection<Student> values = students.stream()
                .collect(toMap(Student::getName,
                        Function.identity(),
                        BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparingInt(Student::getAge))))
                .values();
```

**Explanation**

We're using this overload of `toMap`:

```
toMap​(Function<? super T,? extends K> keyMapper,
      Function<? super T,? extends U> valueMapper,
      BinaryOperator<U> mergeFunction)
```

- `Student::getName` above is the `keyMapper` function used to extract the  values for the map keys.
- `Function.identity()` above is the `valueMapper` function used to extract the values for the map values where `Function.identity()` simply returns the elements in the source them selves i.e. the `Student` objects.
- `BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparingInt(Student::getAge))` above is the merge function used to "decide which Student object to return in the case of a key collission i.e. when two given students have the same name" in this case taking the oldest `Student` .
- Finally, invoking `values()` returns us a collection of students.

The equivalent C# code being:

```
var values = students.GroupBy(s => s.Name, v => v,
                          (a, b) => b.OrderByDescending(e => e.Age).Take(1))
                      .SelectMany(x => x);
```

**Explanation** (for those unfamiliar with .NET)

We're using this extension method of [`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__4_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___0___2__System_Func___1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___2____3__):

```
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult> GroupBy<TSource,TKey,TElement,TResult> 
       (this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
         Func<TSource,TKey> keySelector, 
         Func<TSource,TElement> elementSelector, 
     Func<TKey,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TElement>,TResult> resultSelector);
```

- `s => s.Name` above is the `keySelector` function used to extract the value to group by.
- `v => v` above is the `elementSelector` function used to extract the values i.e. the `Student` objects them selves.
- `b.OrderByDescending(e => e.Age).Take(1)` above is the `resultSelector` which given an `IEnumerable<Student>` represented as `b` takes the oldest student.
- Finally, we apply `.SelectMany(x => x);` to collapse the resulting `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Student>>` into a `IEnumerable<Student>`.

Comment: Nice answer. Just wanted to say that using `v -> v` instead of `Function.identity()` would make the code more similar to the C# equivalent and so easier to compare.

Answer (score 7):

Or without streams:

```
Map<String, Student> map = new HashMap<>();
students.forEach(x -> map.merge(x.getName(), x, (oldV, newV) -> oldV.getAge() > newV.getAge() ? oldV : newV));
Collection<Student> max = map.values();
```

Comment: Thought of this while starting of from your initial suggestion, but then an additional `Map` here, but does `map.merge` save us compared to `toMap`?

Comment: @nullpointer This should have been my answer (I'm supposedly the `without streams guy` here), so I feel I can answer your question... Actually, `Collectors.toMap` uses `Map.merge` under the hood. It even [says so in the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-): `mergeFunction - a merge function, used to resolve collisions between values associated with the same key, as supplied to Map.merge(Object, Object, BiFunction)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you need a grouping only sorted, it is quite simple:

```
Map<String, List<Student>> collect = students.stream() // stream capabilities
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Student::getAge).reversed()) // sort by age, descending
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getName)); // group by name.
```

Output in collect:

- Prince=[Student [Age=24, className=B, Name=Prince]],
- Smith=[Student [Age=24, className=A, Name=Smith]],
- John=[Student [Age=30, className=A, Name=John], Student [Age=24, className=A, Name=John], Student [Age=20, className=B, Name=John]]

Answer (score 1):

Just to mix and merge the other solutions, you could alternatively do :

```
Map<String, Student> nameToStudentMap = new HashMap<>();
Set<Student> finalListOfStudents = students.stream()
        .map(x -> nameToStudentMap.merge(x.getName(), x, (a, b) -> a.getAge() > b.getAge() ? a : b))
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: This violates the requirement of [statelessness](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) on the parameter of `Stream.map`.