# Compare object field values in array list based on conditions and remove if condition is true

Tags: java, java-8, comparator

Suppose these are the java bean classes-

```
class Camp {
      int number;
      User userId;
      Date createDt;
 }

class User {
  private String id;
  private String name;
}
```

I want to remove those records from arrayList of type `Camp` which have same userId but lesser createDt.

Suppose this is the list-

```
// ... the list is already populated
List<Camp> usersList = populatedListOfUser();
```

And this is the method -

```
private List<Camp> skipByComparison(List<Camp> usersList){
    List<Camp> mainList = new ArrayList<Camp>();
    Set<Camp> s = new TreeSet<Camp>(new Comparator<Camp>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Camp o1, Camp o2) {
            if(o1.getUserId().getId().equals(o2.getUserId().getId())) {
                if(o1.getCreatedTs().compareTo(o2.getCreatedTs()) < 0) {
                    usersList.remove(o1);
                    return -1;
                } else {
                    return 1;
                }
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    });
    s.addAll(usersList);
    mainList.addAll(s);
}
```

So when I call -

```
usersList = skipByComparison(usersList);
```

I doesn't get the records from arrayList of type `Camp` which have same userId but lesser createDt.

For ex. if I have 2 records with same `Camp.getUser().getId()` but `record 1` is having `CreateDt` greater than `record 2` then I want to remove `record 2`.

Comment: What is this `UserId userId;` ? Did yiu mean `User userID` ?

Comment: @john- yes. Basically I want to remove those records which do not have latest CreateDt ONLY when Camp.getUser().getId() is same. For ex. if I have 2 records with same Camp.getUser().getId() but record 1 is having CreateDt greater than record 2 then I want to remove record 2.

Comment: Isn't there a `return` in `skipByComparison()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update your code as:

```
private List<Camp> skipByComparison(List<Camp> usersList){
    Set<Camp> s = new TreeSet<>((o1, o2) -> o1.getUserId().getId().equals(o2.getUserId().getId()) ? 
            o1.getCreateDt().compareTo(o2.getCreateDt()) : 0);
    s.addAll(usersList);
    return new ArrayList<>(s);
}
```

or better you can use `Collectors` and streams to solve it as:

```
private List<Camp> skipByComparisonStream(List<Camp> usersList) {
    return new ArrayList<>(usersList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(c -> c.getUserId().getId(),
                    Function.identity(),
                    (a, b) -> a.getCreateDt().after(b.getCreateDt()) ? a : b))
            .values());
}
```

**Explanation** : Your `Comparator` currently doesn't return any value for the case when the two dates could be `equal`, you should probably just rely on the `compareTo` implementation of `Date` class for that :

```
Set<Camp> s = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<Camp>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Camp o1, Camp o2) {
        return o1.getUserId().getId().equals(o2.getUserId().getId()) 
                ? o1.getCreateDt().compareTo(o2.getCreateDt()) : 0;
    }
});
```

Once you do this, you can simplify it using lambda expression as:

```
Set<Camp> s = new TreeSet<>((o1, o2) -> o1.getUserId().getId().equals(o2.getUserId().getId())
        ? o1.getCreateDt().compareTo(o2.getCreateDt()) : 0);
```

The rest of the modification that I did was to simplify the execution order and cleanup redundant initialisation.

**Aside**: I just got corrected in another question and would recomment you as well to instead use [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) for `createDt` attribute.

Comment: You guys are amazing with latest java8 knowledge. Superb!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `toMap` collector:

```
Collection<Camp> values = usersList.stream()
                .collect(toMap(c -> c.getUser().getId(),
                        Function.identity(),
                        BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Camp::getCreateDt))))
                .values();
```

[see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53635022/java-8-lambda-filtering-based-on-condition-as-well-as-order/53635060#53635060) answer for an explanation as to how toMap works